# Module is not installing in cpan in local path

Tags: perl, cpan

I am trying to install [Getopt::Long::Subcommand](https://metacpan.org/pod/Getopt::Long::Subcommand) module on my account on a cluster local folder on cpan. First i set the local path to cpan by following bellow steps.

```
o conf makepl_arg 'PREFIX=/home/user/perl5' 
o conf mbuild_arg '--install_base /home/user/perl5'
o conf mbuild_install_arg '--install_base /home/user/perl5'
o conf mbuildpl_arg '--install-base /home/user/perl5'
o conf commit
```

then `export PERL5LIB=”/home/user/perl5/`

then `cpan>install Getopt::Long::Subcommand`

I am getting following error:

```
PERLANCAR/Log-ger-0.038.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make -- OK
Running make test
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 /software/Perl/5.18.1/uv2000/bin/perl "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-e" "test_harness(0, 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/*.t
t/00-compile.t ............ ok     
t/01-basic.t .............. 1/? Subroutine My::P1::log_warn redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 75.
Subroutine My::P1::log_error redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 75.
Subroutine My::P1::log_fatal redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 75.
Subroutine My::P1::log_info redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 75.
Subroutine My::P1::log_trace redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 75.
Subroutine My::P1::log_debug redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 75.
Subroutine My::P1::log_is_warn redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 75.
Subroutine My::P1::log_is_error redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 75.
Subroutine My::P1::log_is_fatal redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 75.
Subroutine My::P1::log_is_info redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 75.
Subroutine My::P1::log_is_trace redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 75.
Subroutine My::P1::log_is_debug redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 75.
Subroutine Log::ger::Obj2bbad20::warn redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 86.
Subroutine Log::ger::Obj2bbad20::error redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 86.
Subroutine Log::ger::Obj2bbad20::fatal redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 86.
Subroutine Log::ger::Obj2bbad20::info redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 86.
Subroutine Log::ger::Obj2bbad20::trace redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 86.
Subroutine Log::ger::Obj2bbad20::debug redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 86.
Subroutine Log::ger::Obj2bbad20::is_warn redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 86.
Subroutine Log::ger::Obj2bbad20::is_error redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 86.
Subroutine Log::ger::Obj2bbad20::is_fatal redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 86.
Subroutine Log::ger::Obj2bbad20::is_info redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 86.
Subroutine Log::ger::Obj2bbad20::is_trace redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 86.
Subroutine Log::ger::Obj2bbad20::is_debug redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 86.
Subroutine My::P1::log_warn redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 75.
Subroutine My::P1::log_error redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 75.
Subroutine My::P1::log_fatal redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 75.
Subroutine My::P1::log_info redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 75.
Subroutine My::P1::log_debug redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 75.
Subroutine My::P1::log_is_warn redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 75.
Subroutine My::P1::log_is_error redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 75.
Subroutine My::P1::log_is_fatal redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 75.
Subroutine My::P1::log_is_info redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 75.
Subroutine My::P1::log_is_trace redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 75.
Subroutine My::P1::log_is_debug redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 75.
Subroutine Log::ger::Obj2bbad20::warn redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 86.
Subroutine Log::ger::Obj2bbad20::error redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 86.
Subroutine Log::ger::Obj2bbad20::fatal redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 86.
Subroutine Log::ger::Obj2bbad20::info redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 86.
Subroutine Log::ger::Obj2bbad20::debug redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 86.
Subroutine Log::ger::Obj2bbad20::is_warn redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 86.
Subroutine Log::ger::Obj2bbad20::is_error redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 86.
Subroutine Log::ger::Obj2bbad20::is_fatal redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 86.
Subroutine Log::ger::Obj2bbad20::is_info redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 86.
Subroutine Log::ger::Obj2bbad20::is_trace redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 86.
Subroutine Log::ger::Obj2bbad20::is_debug redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 86.
Subroutine My::P1::log_warn redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 75.
Subroutine My::P1::log_error redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 75.
Subroutine My::P1::log_fatal redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 75.
Subroutine My::P1::log_info redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 75.
Subroutine My::P1::log_debug redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 75.
Subroutine My::P1::log_is_warn redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 75.
Subroutine My::P1::log_is_error redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 75.
Subroutine My::P1::log_is_fatal redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 75.
Subroutine My::P1::log_is_info redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 75.
Subroutine My::P1::log_is_trace redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 75.
Subroutine My::P1::log_is_debug redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 75.
Subroutine Log::ger::Obj2bbad20::warn redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 86.
Subroutine Log::ger::Obj2bbad20::error redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 86.
Subroutine Log::ger::Obj2bbad20::fatal redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 86.
Subroutine Log::ger::Obj2bbad20::info redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 86.
Subroutine Log::ger::Obj2bbad20::debug redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 86.
Subroutine Log::ger::Obj2bbad20::is_warn redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 86.
Subroutine Log::ger::Obj2bbad20::is_error redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 86.
Subroutine Log::ger::Obj2bbad20::is_fatal redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 86.
Subroutine Log::ger::Obj2bbad20::is_info redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 86.
Subroutine Log::ger::Obj2bbad20::is_trace redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 86.
Subroutine Log::ger::Obj2bbad20::is_debug redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 86.
Subroutine My::P1::log_warn redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 75.
Subroutine My::P1::log_error redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 75.
Subroutine My::P1::log_fatal redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 75.
Subroutine My::P1::log_is_warn redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 75.
Subroutine My::P1::log_is_error redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 75.
Subroutine My::P1::log_is_fatal redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 75.
Subroutine My::P1::log_is_info redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 75.
Subroutine My::P1::log_is_trace redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 75.
Subroutine My::P1::log_is_debug redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 75.
Subroutine Log::ger::Obj2bbad20::warn redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 86.
Subroutine Log::ger::Obj2bbad20::error redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 86.
Subroutine Log::ger::Obj2bbad20::fatal redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 86.
Subroutine Log::ger::Obj2bbad20::is_warn redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 86.
Subroutine Log::ger::Obj2bbad20::is_error redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 86.
Subroutine Log::ger::Obj2bbad20::is_fatal redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 86.
Subroutine Log::ger::Obj2bbad20::is_info redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 86.
Subroutine Log::ger::Obj2bbad20::is_trace redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 86.
Subroutine Log::ger::Obj2bbad20::is_debug redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 86.
Subroutine My::P1::log_warn redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 75.
Subroutine My::P1::log_error redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 75.
Subroutine My::P1::log_fatal redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 75.
Subroutine My::P1::log_is_warn redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 75.
Subroutine My::P1::log_is_error redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 75.
Subroutine My::P1::log_is_fatal redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 75.
Subroutine My::P1::log_is_info redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 75.
Subroutine My::P1::log_is_trace redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 75.
Subroutine My::P1::log_is_debug redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 75.
Subroutine Log::ger::Obj2bbad20::warn redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 86.
Subroutine Log::ger::Obj2bbad20::error redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 86.
Subroutine Log::ger::Obj2bbad20::fatal redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 86.
Subroutine Log::ger::Obj2bbad20::is_warn redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 86.
Subroutine Log::ger::Obj2bbad20::is_error redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 86.
Subroutine Log::ger::Obj2bbad20::is_fatal redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 86.
Subroutine Log::ger::Obj2bbad20::is_info redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 86.
Subroutine Log::ger::Obj2bbad20::is_trace redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 86.
Subroutine Log::ger::Obj2bbad20::is_debug redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 86.
Subroutine My::P1::log_warn redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 75.
Subroutine My::P1::log_error redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 75.
Subroutine My::P1::log_fatal redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 75.
Subroutine My::P1::log_is_warn redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 75.
Subroutine My::P1::log_is_error redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 75.
Subroutine My::P1::log_is_fatal redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 75.
Subroutine My::P1::log_is_info redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 75.
Subroutine My::P1::log_is_trace redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 75.
Subroutine My::P1::log_is_debug redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 75.
Subroutine Log::ger::Obj2bbad20::warn redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 86.
Subroutine Log::ger::Obj2bbad20::error redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 86.
Subroutine Log::ger::Obj2bbad20::fatal redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 86.
Subroutine Log::ger::Obj2bbad20::is_warn redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 86.
Subroutine Log::ger::Obj2bbad20::is_error redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 86.
Subroutine Log::ger::Obj2bbad20::is_fatal redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 86.
Subroutine Log::ger::Obj2bbad20::is_info redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 86.
Subroutine Log::ger::Obj2bbad20::is_trace redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 86.
Subroutine Log::ger::Obj2bbad20::is_debug redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 86.
Subroutine My::P1::log_warn redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 75.
Subroutine My::P1::log_error redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 75.
Subroutine My::P1::log_fatal redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 75.
Subroutine My::P1::log_is_warn redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 75.
Subroutine My::P1::log_is_error redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 75.
Subroutine My::P1::log_is_fatal redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 75.
Subroutine My::P1::log_is_info redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 75.
Subroutine My::P1::log_is_trace redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 75.
Subroutine My::P1::log_is_debug redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 75.
Subroutine Log::ger::Obj2bbad20::warn redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 86.
Subroutine Log::ger::Obj2bbad20::error redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 86.
Subroutine Log::ger::Obj2bbad20::fatal redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 86.
Subroutine Log::ger::Obj2bbad20::is_warn redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 86.
Subroutine Log::ger::Obj2bbad20::is_error redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 86.
Subroutine Log::ger::Obj2bbad20::is_fatal redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 86.
Subroutine Log::ger::Obj2bbad20::is_info redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 86.
Subroutine Log::ger::Obj2bbad20::is_trace redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 86.
Subroutine Log::ger::Obj2bbad20::is_debug redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 86.
Subroutine My::P1::log_warn redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 75.
Subroutine My::P1::log_error redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 75.
Subroutine My::P1::log_fatal redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 75.
Subroutine My::P1::log_is_warn redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 75.
Subroutine My::P1::log_is_error redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 75.
Subroutine My::P1::log_is_fatal redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 75.
Subroutine My::P1::log_is_info redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 75.
Subroutine My::P1::log_is_trace redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 75.
Subroutine My::P1::log_is_debug redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 75.
Subroutine Log::ger::Obj2bbad20::warn redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 86.
Subroutine Log::ger::Obj2bbad20::error redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 86.
Subroutine Log::ger::Obj2bbad20::fatal redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 86.
Subroutine Log::ger::Obj2bbad20::is_warn redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 86.
Subroutine Log::ger::Obj2bbad20::is_error redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 86.
Subroutine Log::ger::Obj2bbad20::is_fatal redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 86.
Subroutine Log::ger::Obj2bbad20::is_info redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 86.
Subroutine Log::ger::Obj2bbad20::is_trace redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 86.
Subroutine Log::ger::Obj2bbad20::is_debug redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 86.
Subroutine My::P1::log_warn redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 75.
Subroutine My::P1::log_error redefined at /home/user/.cpan/build/Log-ger-0.038-Zc2iQS/blib/lib/Log/ger.pm line 75.
```

Comment: Since the compile test failed, I'd start looking there. This looks like a test issues and not a configuration issue.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So testing is necessary to complete the installation and it is also showing dependencies missing. So that means the module is not installed?

Comment: Well, if the module doesn't compile, it doesn't matter if it's installed. It still stops your program. Since you didn't include all of the output, we don't know what's happening.

Comment: I guess the output is too long to post. If you could let me know which part to post I could do that.

Comment: start where the first error shows up.

Comment: Update your question. Don't put that stuff in comments.

Comment: I have updated my question where the error starts.

Comment: Try to install the dependent module `Log::ger` separately to better understand what the problem can be. What errors do you get if you run from the shell `cpan Log::ger` ?

Comment: Same error is coming as mentioned above but at the end it is showing             
 Result: PASS
  PERLANCAR/Log-ger-0.038.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make test -- OK
Running make install
Appending installation info to /home/user/perl5/lib/perl5/5.18.1/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/perllocal.pod
  PERLANCAR/Log-ger-0.038.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make install  -- OK